# Having issues with Node Red and IIS URL Rewrite

Tags: iis, dashboard, node-red

I'm new to both Node-Red as well as IIS.

I am using URL rewrite to rewrite **localhost:1880** to https://example.com which will show the Node Red Flow Editor. I managed to get the Node Red Flow editor working fine with the URL rewrite and I am able to access it using https://example.com.

I am having issues with accessing the Node Red Dashboard (**localhost:1880/ui**) After doing the URL Rewrite, I am unable to access the dashboard https://example.com/ui. However, I am still able to do access the dashboard using **localhost:1880/ui**.

After this, I went to the **settings.js** and uncommented **httpAdminRoot: '/flow'**. This changed the url to access the Flow Editor (**localhost:1880/flow**).
I also uncommented the **ui: {path: "/"}** which changed the url to access the Dashboard (**localhost:1880/**).

Keeping the same URL Rewrite rules, I am still unable to access the dashboard with **https://example.com** but I am able to access the Flow Editor using https://example.com/flow.

This is the error I get after trying to access **https://example.com**
[image: Error Message]

Inbound/Outbound Rules
[image: Inbound]

[image: Outbound]

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Could you please confirm that you will type `example.com/ui` in the browser and it should rewrite the URL to `localhost:1880/ui`? or you will type  `localhost:1880/ui` in the browser and it should rewrite to `example.com/ui`?

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT when I type example.com/ui , it should rewrite to localhost:1880/ui thus showing the Node Red dashboard.

Comment: @Mervy , please check the example I posted in my answer. It could help you fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a test with the URL Rewrite rule below. It could help you rewrite `example.com/ui` to `localhost:1880/ui`.

```
 <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="test_rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example.com" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/ui$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:1880/ui" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

Output:

[image]

Further, you could modify the rule as per your own requirements.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer @Deepak-MSFT however, now I have an error when I type in example.com/ui . I get Server Error, 500 - Internal server error, There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.